# Using JS to create a table

Tags: recursion

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244458/using-angularjs-to-create-a-recursive-table-with-more-than-1-column) but the solution is only limited to 1 column.

Comment: This is definitely a case of The XY Problem.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378.  You have some unknown *problem* which has led you to a design decision that involves recursion as a *solution*.  Instead of asking about the *problem*, you are asking how to make the *solution* work, but your code and fiddle doesn't really illustrate how this data is related, making recursive debugging very difficult.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that recursion is a bad idea, only that you aren't really demonstrating *why* your data is recursive, and what the structure of the data has to do with multiple columns at all....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a tree representation as opposed to a table?

this widget should work for this:
http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/

Each line could also have multiple columns if you expand the node template.